# Is it right expression? "It is context specific"

Tags: expressions

While I watch a [youtube video](https://youtu.be/ICI5ZxhsB3w) (39:08), which involves some conversations between two persons, I found a expression.

It was roughly:

> "What would we say?" (to express the konglish 비쥬얼/bijyueol)
> "I think it's context-specific"

And considering the entire conversations and subtitle, I concluded that It means "It is different and determined depending on the context." But soon, I found that there is few information about it on Google. So I happen to have a sort of doubt whether it is a common expression many people use or almost nobody uses.

So, I wonder if is it okay that I use the expression in earnest.

Comment: What video?  Please share the link and the time when this is said

Comment: @Here, https://youtu.be/ICI5ZxhsB3w 39 : 08

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the proper translation of a sentence with the word *bijyueol* depends on the context in which the word is used.  The speaker gives three different examples of contexts in which the word could be used in Korean: To talk about the appearance of a meal (in contrast to the flavour), or someone's hair cut, or how a movie is lit and shot (in contrast to the dialogue or the acting).  These are three different contexts and the translation of *bijyueol* could be different in the three contexts.

"It is context-specfic" is a fairly common thing to say.  You might also just say "It depends on the context"

Answer (score 0):

When we say something is "context specific" - it means it is dependent on the context in which it is used.

Here's a different example.

The word "to", on its own, without any context, can have many different meanings, but once we use it in a sentence along with other words (the context) its meaning becomes clear.   So it would be true to say that the meaning of the word "to" is context specific.